# Can I make my jquery responsive for all devices?

Tags: jquery, css

I am dealing with mobile friendly website and using that I applied multiple animations using jquery. I wrote jquery for desktop as well as laptop also as below:

```
function mobani1()  
{$("#animate1").fadeIn('slow').animate({'display':'inline-
block','margin-   left':'180px','margin-bottom':'6px'},1000,function(){ 

$('.1st').animate({'opacity': '0.9'},400,
     function(){$('.1st').animate({'opacity':'1'})})});
     $("#animate1").fadeIn('slow').animate({'margin-bottom':'0px','margin-left':'-140px'},1000)
       .fadeOut('slow');}

     function mobani2(){ $(".2nd").fadeIn('slow').animate({'margin-left':'20px','margin-bottom':'2px'},'slow',function(){$('.1st').animate({'opacity':'0.5'},1000,
     function(){$('.1st').animate({'opacity':'1'},'slow')})}).fadeOut();  
     $(".2nd").fadeIn('slow').animate({'margin-bottom':'0px','margin-left':'-150px'},'slow')
     .fadeOut('slow');}

    var interval1=[mobani1,mobani2,mobani3];
     var index =0;
     $(document).ready(function(){
              window.setInterval( function(){ 
                  interval1[index++ % interval1.length]()
                                     },10800); // total time taken by animation is 10800
    });
```

Now, I have various mobile devices so in every devices, I can't set `margin-left` `margin-bottom` as per given here. For example, here `margin-left: 180px` given but what happens if my mobile have 500px, 800px various width? So, how can I write above jquery for mobile friendly versions.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn´t use fixed values like pixels. Use em,vh,vw instead.

Comment: Solution for javascript fanatics is to use `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()` for calculating of margins.

Comment: Not sure the main propose of your code but I think should be interesting reading about the difference between responsive and adaptive design.
https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-responsive-and-adaptive-design/

Answer (score 0):

Better you go with **media-queries** for cross browser and mobile devices.
you can learn more on mediaQueries from W3schools  :http://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp and from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries